# Adding marks to Chrome's Timeline tool?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes, it's difficult to tell when a piece of code starts and when it ends. Is it possible to add markers to Chrome's Timeline tool?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `console.timeStamp(markName)`. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/track-executions#marking-the-timeline for reference.

Comment: That page on `developers.google.com` is marked as "deprecated", and `console.timeStamp()` no longer seems to add anything to the Chrome DevTools' Performance display. Is there a new API?

Answer (score 4):

`console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` now show under Performance's **Console** section (next to Main, GPU, Network, etc.).

For example:

```
console.time('Hello world!');
console.time('Hi world!');
setTimeout(() => console.timeEnd('Hello world!'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.timeEnd('Hi world!'), 2000);
```

This looks like this:

[image]